# The reputation recalc page has direct side effects based only on GET data (and not POST)

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-recalc, exploit

This is bad because if I do

```
![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?recalc=true
```

in a post, then whoever visits the post will have their reputation recalculated.

Comment: PS: I was **REALLY** tempted to do that for real, but I imagine a lot of people would have been pissed =)

Comment: A quick and dirty fix would be to use the parameter only if the HTTP_REFERER is empty (i.e. the URL was typed in by hand).

Comment: Was it not a bug that they had the wrong rep in the first place?

Comment: Funny, but I think this might be a *good* side effect, except of course for 1) the fact that the recalc mechanism may get overwhelmed and 2) the inevitable flood of "Where my Rep go?" questions.

Comment: [This link will recalculate your reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?recalc=false)  (Well, not actually)

Comment: @gno We should start answering the "why do /reputation and the top bar disagree on my total rep?" posts with `![](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?recalc=true) Now that you've seen this answer, the problem is solved`

Comment: Woo hoo... I gained 6 rep! :p

Comment: (Now wondering if the same could be done for upvotes...! Ah, no: `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/71722/vote/0`)

Comment: @Arjan: you can't, it's a POST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I get for adding features on meds*.

After our next build you'll have to use a form to submit this request (all XSRF'd up) from a vanilla /reputation page.

<sub>*The psychotropic effects of [Pepto-Bismol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepto-Bismol) being well known.</sub>

Comment: Should have skipped the meds and just taken some time for REST.

Comment: Seems to me those meds do not slow you down! :-)